# Creating Eclipse Code Format XML From Java File (Reverse Engineering)

Tags: eclipse, formatting, reverse-engineering

I am working on a large project with thousands of java files, original author of project used some custom formatting to format java file which we don't have now, I tried to create a similar format in eclipse but it did't worked for me because there is still many differences, after writing code when i do press **Ctrl+Shift+F** it formats the document, but main problem comes when we have to merge file or compare with previous SVN version of file, because formatting of file changes, SVN shows thousands of changes which are not even true changes, and it even become impossible to merge it properly, What i want if i could extract format XML by giving my java file is it possible , Reverse engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way to reverse engineer a XML file from your code, but here is what you can certainly do:

- Check out the code and freeze the trunk so that noone else can commit the code
- Apply whatever formatting rules you want to apply - and apply this across your codebase
- Once you have done formatting changes- do whatever sanity checks you do before committing code (Like build, basic tests etc.)
- Now commit this code as "Formatting changes only- NO CODE CHANGED" - that way you have a logical commit of only formatting changes
- Now ask other developers to update their codebase. Thus you will have changed to new formatting rules without affecting anything.
- Also whatever rules you have in XML - ask other developers to implement in their IDE - so future commits are consistent in style and formatting.